# HTML5 video autoplay

Tags: javascript, html

On my [website page](http://work.bozoncontent.com/chaudfontaine/) I've added an autoplay on the video while being muted. Everytime I close my browser and visit the page the autoplay stops after 2 seconds. This is the code I've used in an HMTL raw block with VC:

```
<video id="vid" preload="auto" muted loop>
 <source src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/CHAUDFONTAINE-FUSION-HD.mp4#t=0" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
 vid.oncanplaythrough = function() {
  vid.play();
 };

</script>
```

I've also tried it without javascript and just use "autoplay" in  the video tag but the result is te same.

Comment: It doesn't stop for me btw. It loops through the video infinitely which I suppose it's supposed to do?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a bad connection and it's buffering? Because I'm with thepio, it doesn't stop for me.

Comment: What browser are you using? Also, check the console, any errors?

Comment: Note: The video tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions

Comment: Yesterday it worked fine for me but this morning it kept stopping after 2 seconds, maybe it was indeed a bad connection this morning! I tested it out with FF, Chrome and Safari. Glad to hear it works fine on other computers

Answer (score 0):

From [*docs*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video),

> *The `autoplay` attribute has precedence over `preload`. If `autoplay` is specified, the browser would obviously need to start downloading the video for playback.*

In your case, as `autoplay` attribute is present, video starts playing once sufficient part of video is buffered to be play. Once `oncanplaythrough` event is `fulfilled`, `play` event is invoked again!

Comment: In my example there is no autoplay attribute at the moment. I've tried it with autoplay and without preload but still the same. So oncanplaythrough and play can't work together?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6b7bgk9a/ here you go :)! In fiddle it works fine, it's just that sometime in my browser it stops after 2 seconds